# Grunt; Warning: uncommitted changes in working directory

Tags: git, repository, gruntjs, npm, githooks

I'm trying to setup a Grunt to commit to a repository on Github.

In Gruntjs I have;

```
 buildcontrol: {
            options: {
                dir: 'dist',
                commit: true,
                push: true,
                message: 'Built %sourceName% from commit %sourceCommit% on branch %sourceBranch%'
            },
            pages: {
                options: {
                    remote: 'git@github.com:numediaweb/test.git',
                    branch: 'gh-pages'
                }
            },
            local: {
                options: {
                    remote: '../',
                    branch: 'build'
                }
            }
        },
```

But when I do the command `grunt buildcontrol:pages` I recieve this warning;

```
Running "buildcontrol:pages" (buildcontrol) task
Warning: There are uncommitted changes in your working directory.
Please commit changes to the main project before you commit to
the built code.
```

I followed [this tutorial](http://yeoman.io/deployment.html) and [this one](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/grunt-build-control) but couldn't get it working.. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It is all here

https://github.com/X1011/git-directory-deploy

sharch and you will find

Comment: This is not about Grunt build control, and to tell you the truth that's all Greek to me :(

I use yeoman to create an app, I installed the grunt-build-control, I executed git init in the main dir (not in "myApp/app") which created a "myApp/.git") .. running grunt build populates the "myApp/dist" directory but then I'm lost!

Are there any easy step by step (for dummies) on how to deploy my whole app, say, to beanstalkapp and set grunt to build / commit and push my whole app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `connectCommits` property: https://github.com/robwierzbowski/grunt-build-control#connectcommits

I added this to prevent building and pushing code that can't be traced back to a commit on the parent project. If you're doing a lot of hacking at the start of a project you can set this to false, but once you're up and running I think it's a good idea to leave it on.